# Laravel/Eloquent conditions on subproperties don't apply

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following models:

- Client

  - belongsToMany(Group)
- Group

  - belongsToMany(Client)

What I wanted is an array of all groups, where each group contains the clients belonging to it.

I was able to achieve this with the following code:

```
Group::with('clients')->get();
```

Now I want to only get the groups and clients where the client's status property is 0. So if there are multiple clients in a group, then the result should not contain clients with a status !=1. Additionally, if this condition returns 0 clients for a group, the group should also NOT be contained in the final result.

What I tried so far:

```
Group::with(['clients' => function($query) {
  $query->where('clients.status', '!=', 1);
}])->whereHas('clients', function($query) {
  $query->where('clients.status', '!=', 1);
})->get();
```

Somehow, none of both where-conditions apply when I execute the query. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: You say you you "want to only get the groups where the client's status property is 1", but your query has `clients.status != 1`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @tptcat Was a typo, i fixed it

Comment: What does your pivot table that links users and groups look like? Is it simply `user_id` and `group_id`?

Comment: Exactly. There are no additional properties involved in the pivot table. (Besides created, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

As per laravel documentation, the result you are expecting should be the result of following statement:

```
Group::whereHas('clients', function($query) {
  $query->where('status', '!=', 1);
})->get()
```

Here is the reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: @kreilinger - This would work the best. Your other checks you mention should occur after this query. I don't think you can do everything you mentioned in one big query.

Comment: As I mentioned in my first post, I need to include the clients in the groups. Altering your code to the following does not work (clients with status 0 are included.)

`Group::orderBy('number')->with('clients')->whereHas('clients', function($query) {
                    $query->where('status', '!=', 0);
                })->get();`

Comment: @kreilinger You were using `'clients.status'` in the where clause. Has it resolved your issue? Is it working now?